# Need to change textarea text on select field change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As I write in title I need to change textarea text when select field changed.

```js
$('#sel').on('change', function() {
  var option = $('option:selected', this).val();
  $('#message').text(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <select class="form-control  input-margin" id="sel" placeholder="Select A Message">
    <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Just write my own message</option>
    <option value="Have a great day, happy birthday!">Have a great day, happy birthday!</option>
    <option value="Happy birthday to you!">Happy birthday to you!</option>
    <option value="Have a lovely day.">Have a lovely day.</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control input-margin" style="width:1000px !important; height: 200px !important;" type="text" placeholder="Write a Message here." parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="first"></textarea>
</div>
```

When I change value of select field nothing happend in the textarea? Why ? Do you see any bugs here? WHat can be a solution?

Comment: Works just fine for me,

Comment: Try to use `$('#message').val(option);` instead

Comment: See the error message in dev console

Comment: there is no error message... maybe is probem becouse this is into bootstrap modal widnow ?

Comment: As you can see from the snippet I added to your question, the code works fine. Please check for errors in the console and ensure you're running your code in a document.ready event handler

Comment: no need of it to be in document.ready The document is already loaded before you change the select element.

Comment: your code is working. https://jsfiddle.net/kapila_perera/xLddshLc/
error should be in somewhere. update the rest of the code or check your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code into **$(document).ready()**

**[.ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) -**
The ready event occurs when the DOM (document object model) has been loaded.

Because this event occurs after the document is ready, it is a good place to have all other jQuery events and functions. Like in the example above.

Please see the below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sel').on('change', function() {
    var option = $('option:selected', this).val();

  $('#message').text(option);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
           <select class="form-control  input-margin" id="sel" placeholder="Select A Message">
    <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Just write my own message</option>
<option value="Have a great day, happy birthday!">Have a great day, happy birthday!</option>
<option value="Happy birthday to you!">Happy birthday to you!</option>
<option value="Have a lovely day.">Have a lovely day.</option>


      </select>
      </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control input-margin" style="width:1000px !important; height: 200px !important;" type="text" placeholder="Write a Message here." parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="first"></textarea>
      </div>
```

**EDIT:-**
And also **DO NOT FORGOT** to add reference on your HTML page into `<head>` tag as below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have document ready and that is no problem ... also when I post code in browser console wont work again ...

Answer (score 0):

add Script in head tag i.e

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sel').on('change', function() {
  var option = $('option:selected', this).val();

$('#message').text(option);
});
});
</script>
```

put this in body tag

```
<div class="col-md-6">
           <select class="form-control  input-margin" id="sel" placeholder="Select A Message">
    <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Just write my own message</option>
<option value="Have a great day, happy birthday!">Have a great day, happy birthday!</option>
<option value="Happy birthday to you!">Happy birthday to you!</option>
<option value="Have a lovely day.">Have a lovely day.</option>


      </select>
      </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
      <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control input-margin" style="width:1000px !important; height: 200px !important;" type="text" placeholder="Write a Message here." parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="first"></textarea>
      </div>
```

Comment: @Aleks Per try it.. this will help you

Comment: hm, no... works when form is out of modal window ... when I put this into modal window wont work